# Maven build fails even though classes are available and imported

Tags: eclipse, maven

My maven project is not building successfully and is giving the error: cannot find symbol.

All third party apis are recognizing properly because i configured those in pom.xml, but when coming to my module, one package classes are not coming in another package, I imported those classes with the package name, I get a compile time error saying

```
TestClassImpl.java:311: cannot find symbol
```

In eclipse it is showing as Multiple markers at this line

- TestClass cannot be resolved to a type
- Watchpoint:TestClassImpl
  [access and modification] - testClass

Comment: how do you know you have configured it right?  Where is TestClass? In your project or in a JAR that your project depending on?  And, there is no one can guess what's happening without related snippets of config

Comment: TestClass is available in my project itself, not in any jar. And until yesterday it worked correctly. Now only im getting problem, some thing is missing.

Comment: You need to give us more information. E.g. pom.xml contents, and the problem classes.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this is that `TestClassImpl.java` is somewhere below `src/test` and you try to use it from code in `src/main`. That's not allowed; Maven separates those two classpaths to make sure test code cannot possibly leak into production.

So while the code in `src/main` is visible to code below `src/test`, the opposite isn't true.